# SSRS Dropdown for column items

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I've built a SSRS report using a SQL query for the Dataset1. I'm trying to build a parameter that gives the users a dropdown list. I ended up creating a Dataset2 to get distinct values for the parameter Label and then use Dataset1 for the actual value (allowing for multiple values).

EDITING PER Request:

Dataset1 query:

```
SELECT vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.Type
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.SOPTYPE
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.SOPNUMBE
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.Date_Document
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.ExtendedPrice
    ,IV00101.ITEMNMBR
    ,IV00101.USCATVLS_2 AS Family
    ,IV00101.USCATVLS_3 AS Product
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.VoidStatus
    ,RM00101.CUSTCLAS
    ,GL00100.MNACSGMT
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.BillTo_CustNum
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.BillTo_CustName
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.sales_territory
    ,vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.ITEMDESC
FROM (
    (
        test.dbo.vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion INNER JOIN test.dbo.IV00101 IV00101 ON vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.ITEMNMBR = IV00101.ITEMNMBR
        ) INNER JOIN test.dbo.RM00101 RM00101 ON vu_SOPWork_HistoryUnion.BillTo_CustNum = RM00101.CUSTNMBR
    )
INNER JOIN test.dbo.GL00100 GL00100 ON IV00101.IVSLSIDX = GL00100.ACTINDX
```

Dataset2 Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IV00101.USCATVLS_2 AS FamilyNames
FROM test.dbo.IV00101
```

I would like to use the Dataset2 "FamilyNames" as the label options against Dataset1 "Family" values. Dataset2 gets the distinct values that I want to put in the drop down for the user to choose and then receive all rows that has that value in Dataset1 "Family". I'm an expert on not giving enough information. Hope this helps you help me. Thanks.

Comment: can you share sample or image of what u r doing in dataset2 and what you actually want? I hope you are not trying to refer the report items in parameter expressions etc.

Comment: It just selecting Distinct values:

Select Distinct Column AS Type from Database

I'm just trying to give a dropdown so the user can show specific values in a column.

Comment: from what? You need to show your Dataset1 query and what you are trying to see in your parameter list.

Comment: I have a column with multiple values, **1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3** and I'm trying to setup a parameter to only list **1, 2, 3** and then show all rows with that particular value. The query is a simple select query:

`SELECT vu_Work.Type, vu_Work.Number, vu_Work.Family, vu_Work.Product  FROM   db1.dbo.vu_Work`

Comment: So what column contains the numbers you want as your values and where will the parameter labels come from? Please just edit your question to show everything you have. People will help you but only if they have enough information. Please don't be vague and say "I get it from another dataset", actually show that dataset query. The answer is probably really simple but we're just guessing at the moment.

Comment: Post the SQL Query for Dataset2. I believe if you have Dataset2 setup correctly. then your parameter should just use Dataset2 (for both label and value) and it will all work

Comment: I see your updated question. Now if you setup the parameter to use Dataset2 for both label and value. then make dataset1 to use the parameter you should be all set. I guess I don't understand this part of your question `" I ended up creating a Dataset2 to get distinct values for the parameter Label and then use Dataset1 for the actual value (allowing for multiple values)."`

Comment: I was thinking of it wrong. how do I make dataset1 use the parameter? I added it to the dataset1 properties but when I try and filter using the new dropdown it still doesn't filter.

Comment: don't bother using filters in the dataset, just follow the answer below and do the filtering in your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, do the following..

Create DataSet1 with the query as you have it now but append the following to the end of the query

```
WHERE USCATVLS_2 IN(@Family)
```

When you do this, the @Family parameter will be created automatically in your report, we'll get back to this later.

Create another dataset called Dataset2 (or a more sensible name like 'families' in this case) with the following simple query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT USCATVLS_2 FROM test.dbo.IV00101 ORDER BY USCATVLS_2
```

Edit the @Family parameter:

1. Set it to multi-value
2. Change the available values to be a query
3. Select your 2nd dataset as the datasource
4. Choose USCATVLS_2 as both the labels and values.

Create your report as normal with the tablix/matrix based on Dataset1.

**Notes:**
A few other things you might want to consider, but not required.

- If a list of family names with some kind of ID is available in your database then I suggest you use that for your parameter list, you would also then have to edit the query in dataset1 to match. Remember that the parameter will contain whatever is in the column of the query that you chose as the value column in the dataset that populates the parameter list
- Consider using aliases for table names in your queries rather than the full table names all the time, it makes the code more concise and easier to read.
- Name your datasets according to what they contain or do, e.g. I would call Dataset2 'Families' or something similar as that is what it contains. When your reports get more complex it will make them easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, this worked, but not sure how this differed from when I manually added the parameter. I'll add the parameter through the query from now on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way to set the default value to list all of the options?

Comment: Yes, just set the default values property to the exact same as the available values property. So choose the dataset2 (or whatever you called it) query again and this time just set the values option.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but it's not listing anything until I actually use the dropdown. I'm putting dataset2 and my value under default values section under the Family parameter properties.

Comment: Never mind, I found the issue. I never did check the allow multiple values. Thanks for the help with everything. I'm understanding a bit more now.